# Tragedy About Bear Whose Mom Died

Tags: identification-request, short-stories

Trigger warning: story deals with death, depression, graphic abuse of animals.

I haven't been able to find this short story. I don't recall if I heard it as part of a podcast or read it online. I came across it between 2018 and 2020. It was in English.

The story features a bear whose mother dies. The bear reacts by seeking sympathy from the forest community instead of taking care of itself. The bear's quality of life dramatically declines, ending with it being horrifically captured and abused as a circus performer for humans. Even then, it's just trying to tell everyone that its mom died.